# Calling two methods from table wrapper in a class

Tags: php

I want to create a table which generates data from the database and I need to have update and delete function for each row of data in the table. But i failed to do both update and delete because i put both function in one controller

This is my view file which include the controller to show the data.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr class="table-active">
        <td>Booth ID</td>
        <td>Booth Location</td>
        <td>Participant ID </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php include 'BoothViewController.php'; ?>

    </tr>
    </table>
```

This is my controller to display the data in rows. Each row will have update and delete function. The update function will bring the user to another page while delete function is merely remove that row of data.

```
<?php
require 'boothmodel.php';
$result = viewbooth();
if($result){
    while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<td>".$array["BoothID"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$array["Boothlocation"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$array["ParticipantID"]."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='BoothFormUpdate.php?bid=".$array['BoothID'].
            "&blocation=".$array['Boothlocation']."&pid=".$array['ParticipantID']."'>Update</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='BoothViewController.php?bid=".$array['BoothID'].
            "&blocation=".$array['Boothlocation']."&pid=".$array['ParticipantID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
            }
    return;
}
if(isset($_GET['bid'])){
    $selectedbid = $_GET['bid'];
    $result = deletebooth($selectedbid);
    if($result){
        echo "<script language = 'javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Booth deleted!');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'BoothView.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}?>
```

this is my model.

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
mysqli_select_db($conn, "ims");


function viewbooth(){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM booth";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    return $result;
}

function updatebooth($bid, $newbloc){
    global $conn;
    $update = "UPDATE booth 
            SET Boothlocation='".$newbloc.
            "'WHERE BoothID='".$bid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    return $result;
}

function deletebooth($selectedbid){
    global $conn;
    $delete = "DELETE FROM booth WHERE BoothID=".$selectedbid;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $delete);
    return $result;
}?>
```

I know i can simply do the delete function in another controller but im trying to put all in one controller.

Comment: If you are interested in building MVC apps, check out Laravel framework. It has all the building blocks to create nicely structured apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a basic routing mechanism, e.g.

```
if(isset($_GET['bid'], $_GET['action']))
{
    $selectedbid = $_GET['bid'];
    $action = $_GET['action'];

    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'delete':
          $result = deletebooth($selectedbid);

          if($result){
            echo "<script language = 'javascript'>";
            echo "alert('Booth deleted!');";
            echo "window.location.href = 'BoothView.php';";
            echo "</script>";
          }
          break;

          case 'update':
          // do the updating
          break;
    }
}
```

then you can add update and delete links to your items:

```
<a href="BoothViewController.php?action=update?bid=1">Update item</a>
<a href="BoothViewController.php?action=delete?bid=1">Delete item</a>
```

Your code hardly resembles the MVC pattern and has many issues. However, the routing idea should work.

Comment: it should also be noted if you are using the REST pattern that instead of the parameter you would check the REQUEST_METHOD header and see if it is GET/POST/DELETE.

Comment: Well, yes! I tried to provide a minimal example of how to achieve the goal.

Comment: you did so using a $_GET parameter, not by checking the request method. Only reason I mentioned it.